# Pascal. Рекурсивная функция возвращает 0

Tags: delphi, pascal, рекурсия

Функция считает сумму цифр n числа. Объясните пожалуйста почему функция возвращает 0, хотя debug показывает значение в переменной sum

```
    function SumNum(sum,num:integer):integer;
begin
    if 0 = num then
    begin
        SumNum:=sum;
        exit;
    end;
    SumNum(sum + num mod 10,num div 10);
end;
```

Comment: [Result - Переменная, используемая для хранения возвращаемого значения функции.](https://delphisources.ru/pages/faq/faq_delphi_basics/Result.php.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так, как вы хотите - рекурсивно, с двумя аргументами - надо писать не

```
SumNum(sum + num mod 10,num div 10);
```

а

```
SumNum := SumNum(sum + num mod 10,num div 10);
```

См. https://ideone.com/ToU2VT

Comment: Уже решил, всё же спасибо, не могли бы вы объяснить почему так? Ведь перед возвращением в переменой sum есть данные

Comment: @Taurinz Используйте Result, всё станет яснее

Comment: Только если n = 0, а что возвращается, если n не ноль? Возвращаемый результат просто игнорируется...

Comment: @MBo Спасибо) result так-же вернул 0. Яснее не стало:с

Comment: Если if не срабатывает, функция просто ничего не возвращает. sum - параметр по значению, при каждом вызове создаётся новая копия. К возвращаемому значению это прямого отношения не имеет.